# p-adic number, two rational number is considered

Tags: prime-numbers, p-adic-number-theory

Q: Deduce that if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two rational numbers so that for every prime $p$ we have $|\alpha-\beta|_p \leq 1$, and $|\alpha-\beta|_R < 1$, then $\alpha$ equals $\beta$.

In fact, there is a part (i) before this question. Part (i) is to show that for a rational number $\alpha$, prove $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ for all primes $p$ if and only if $\alpha$ is an integer. And I finished this part (i guess i am correct...).

By the way, this question is a part (ii). It gives us a hint that the difference $\alpha-\beta$ must be an integer (by i), then $|\alpha-\beta|_R \leq 1$ forces an equality. What does it means...and how can I do this question? Thank you very much~~

Comment: I will help the rest of us if you tell us what your mathematical background is (what courses you’ve had and are taking) and what you’ve tried so far.

Comment: I have found a book "a course in p adic analysis". It includes this fact. And I will read it and I should be able to finish this question. By the way, thank you very much~

Comment: The point is that for any nonzero rational number $\lambda$, the product $\prod_p|\lambda|_p=1$, if you include among the $p$’s the real absolute value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming part (i) you have mentioned, the answer to your question is straightforward: $\alpha - \beta$ is an integer whose (archimedean) absolute value is less than $1$, so it's $0$.

For a proof to part (i), here's a good first step: write $\alpha = a/b$ in lowest terms, and pick a prime $p$ dividing $b$, assuming $b \neq 1$.

(Of course, the comment by Lubin also gives a proof to part (ii), and his comment is probably worth your while thinking why it's true.)

(One more thing that I guess is worth nitpicking: usually people write $\mathbb{R}$ (\mathbb{R}) instead of $R$ for real numbers.)